# Deserialize JSON returned from JsonDiffPatch.Diff() in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am comparing two json objects using JsonDiffPatch.Diff() method and I get the below JSON Structure:

```js
{
  "complexity": {
    "_t": "a",
    "0": {
      "phases": {
        "_t": "a",
        "0": {
          "activities": {
            "_t": "a",
            "_0": [
              {
                "name": "NAME",
                "sortId": 15,
                "isCritical": true,
                "url": "https://google.com",
                "processGroupName": "pgm",
                "isDeliverable": "no"
              },
              0,
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "3": {
      "phases": {
        "_t": "a",
        "0": {
          "sortId": [
            55,
            0,
            0
          ]
        },
        "1": {
          "activities": {
            "_t": "a",
            "_0": [
              {
                "name": "SName",
                "sortId": 12,
                "isCritical": false,
                "url": "https://google.com",
                "processGroupName": "pgm",
                "isDeliverable": "Yes"
              },
              0,
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result that I want is an object containing List of Phases which contains List of Activities. As per the above JSON I want:
0[Phases and Related Activities]
3[Phases and Related Activities]

I have written the below code:

```
List<JToken> tokens = diffJson.Children().Children().ToList();
        foreach (var token in tokens)
        {

            //Console.WriteLine(token.ToJson());
            var phases = token["0"].Children().Children();
            Console.WriteLine(phases.Count());
            var activities = phases["0"].Children().Children();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

But this will only be for the first set which is for "complexity"["0"]. But how to get the data into an object which contains List.

I have tried the below code also:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        dynamic item = serializer.Deserialize<object>(output);
```

Could anybody help me out in understanding how to Deserialize this complex JSON into simple objects?

I am thinking I will ignore "_t":"a" object under phases and start reading activities(again ignoring "_t": "a" object). Let me see how successful I will be.

Expected Output will be creating objects of below classes:

```
using System;
using System.Generic;
public class Difference {
public List<Phase> Phases { get; set; }
}

public class Phase {
    //For other properties like sortID
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Properties { get; set; }
    public List<Activity> Activites { get; set; }
}

public class Activity {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int sortId { get; set; }
    public bool isCritical { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string processGroupName { get; set; }
    public string isDeliverable { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the code which partially works:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        dynamic item = serializer.Deserialize<object>(output);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> complexity in item["complexity"])
        {
            if (complexity.Key != "_t")
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> phases in complexity.Value["phases"])
                {
                    if (phases.Key != "_t")
                        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> activities in phases.Value["activities"])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(activities.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But this loop breaks when simple key value like sortId comes into picture.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you trying to fetch all `activities` from the current `json`...?

Comment: @vikscool Not only Activities, Activities with phases. So my C# Object will be a list of Phases which contains related activities.

Comment: Please provide an expected output from the given JSON.

Comment: @vikscool I have updated my question with expected output.

Comment: can you specify the `Properties` object, like what should it contain?

Comment: The structure of json is there are multiple phases. Each phase has multiple activities. But there might also be some simple key value pairs like sortId in the above json within each phase. I want such key value pairs in Properties object.

Comment: ok, will post the deserialization solution in a couple of minutes have to modify it to grab the properties as well.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question with some code I am trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per what you have mentioned in the comment on @MarcoSalemo's answer i have modified the Sample `Json` to suit your requirement the `Json` now consists of `3` sub documents and 2 with 1 `activity` each sub-document except for the last one which has 2 `activities` and a `properties` object as `sortId` :

Sample JSON:

```
var jsonString = @"{
            'complexity': {
              '_t': 'a',
              '0': {
                'phases': {
                  '_t': 'a',
                  '0': {
                    'activities': {
                      '_t': 'a',
                      '_0': [
                        {
                          'name': 'NAME',
                          'sortId': 15,
                          'isCritical': true,
                          'url': 'https://google.com',
                          'processGroupName': 'pgm',
                          'isDeliverable': 'no'
                        },
                        0,
                        0
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              '1': {
                'phases': {
                  '_t': 'a',
                  '0': {
                    'activities': {
                      '_t': 'a',
                      '_0': [
                        {
                          'name': 'NAME1',
                          'sortId': 155,
                          'isCritical': true,
                          'url': 'https://google.com',
                          'processGroupName': 'pgm',
                          'isDeliverable': 'no'
                        },
                        0,
                        0
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              '3': {
                'phases': {
                  '_t': 'a',
                  '0': {
                    'sortId': [
                      55,
                      0,
                      0
                    ]
                  },
                  '1': {
                    'activities': {
                      '_t': 'a',
                      '_0': [
                        {
                          'name': 'SName',
                          'sortId': 12,
                          'isCritical': false,
                          'url': 'https://google.com',
                          'processGroupName': 'pgm',
                          'isDeliverable': 'Yes'
                        },
                        0,
                        0
                      ],
                      '_1': [
                        {
                          'name': 'SName1',
                          'sortId': 123,
                          'isCritical': false,
                          'url': 'https://google.com',
                          'processGroupName': 'pgm',
                          'isDeliverable': 'Yes'
                        },
                        0,
                        0
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
      }";
```

And the deserialization is achieved as:

```
var jobj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
List<Phase> Phases = new List<Phase>();                
var complexity = jobj.SelectToken("complexity");
var childrens = complexity.Children().ToList();

for (int i = 1; i < childrens.Count; i++)
{
    var activities = new List<Activity>();
    var _properties = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    var child = childrens[i].Children();//getting all the sub-documets in the json
    foreach (var subChild in child)
    {
       var phases = subChild.SelectToken("phases").Children().ToList();//getting JTokens having key "phases"
       for (int j = 1; j < phases.Count; j++)
       {
          var phaseResult = phases[j].Children().ToList(); //getting all the children of the //phases JToken and itterating over them
          foreach (var item in phaseResult)
          {
             if (item["activities"] != null) //producing the "Activity(s)" object
             {
                var acts = item.SelectToken("activities").Children().ToList();
                for (int k = 1; k < acts.Count; k++)
                {
                   var act = acts[k].Children().ToList();
                   foreach (var entity in act)
                   {
                      var jarvalue = JArray.Parse(entity.ToString()).Children().ToArray()[0].ToString();
                      var objAct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Activity>(jarvalue);
                      activities.Add(objAct);
                   }
                }
             }
             else
             {
                //if not Activity object than producing Properties object
                var _props = item.Children<JToken>().ToList();
                var nProeprties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                foreach (var content in _props)
                {
                   var _contentProp = ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty)content); //converting the property object of JtokenType to JProperty to get the Name and JValue
                                    nProeprties.Add(_contentProp.Name, _contentProp.Value.ToString());                                        
                }

                _properties.Add(nProeprties);
             }
          }
       }
    }
    Phases.Add(new Phase { Activites = activities, Properties = _properties });//appending the extracted output to the mail object "Phases"
 }
```

As per the above sample `json`, the serialized output would be something like this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Phases);

[
{
  "Properties":[

  ],
  "Activites":[
     {
        "name":"NAME",
        "sortId":15,
        "isCritical":true,
        "url":"https://google.com",
        "processGroupName":"pgm",
        "isDeliverable":"no"
     }
  ]
 },
 {
  "Properties":[

  ],
  "Activites":[
     {
        "name":"NAME1",
        "sortId":155,
        "isCritical":true,
        "url":"https://google.com",
        "processGroupName":"pgm",
        "isDeliverable":"no"
     }
  ]
 },
 {
  "Properties":[
     {
        "sortId":"[\r\n  55,\r\n  0,\r\n  0\r\n]"
     }
  ],
  "Activites":[
     {
        "name":"SName",
        "sortId":12,
        "isCritical":false,
        "url":"https://google.com",
        "processGroupName":"pgm",
        "isDeliverable":"Yes"
     },
     {
        "name":"SName1",
        "sortId":123,
        "isCritical":false,
        "url":"https://google.com",
        "processGroupName":"pgm",
        "isDeliverable":"Yes"
     }
  ]
 }
]
```

**Note:**

- I am using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) to serialize/deserialize the json.
- This is just a simple approach there can be many(*Even better*) to achieve what you want. So, please test it out with your data and let me know if it needs a modification.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test it out and let you know :)

Comment: It is working as I needed. Will try different scenarios and update. Thanks Again :)

Comment: Sure, No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `dynamic` and deserialize the json with `JSON.NET`

Comment: Thanks I did that. But I am finding difficulty in actually looping through the object to obtain all the phases and related  activities. The JSOn I have shown is minimal. I get a very huge JSON dynamically. Here if you see under complexity there is two sub objects "0" and "3". Lets say the difference from my original JSON (which contains 10 sub object under complexity) and obtained JSON returns an object similar to the one above but with differences identified in 3, 5, 7, 2 nd position. How do I write a loop for this and other such cases is what I am working on. Any ideas please?